# DAX Switch Logic translated to TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, switch-statement, dax

How would I perform the below DAX expression in TSQL?

```
Channel Mapping: =
     SWITCH(
        TRUE (),
           NOT ( ISERROR ( SEARCH ( "ChannelOne", ChannelFact[ChannelName] ) ) ), "C1",
           NOT ( ISERROR ( SEARCH ( "ChannelTwo", ChannelFact[ChannelName] ) ) ), "C2",
           NOT ( ISERROR ( SEARCH ( "Channel2", ChannelFact[ChannelName] ) ) ), "C2",

        "Not Mapped"
)
```

I think it needs the CASE logic but unsure how to put together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE ChannelName WHEN "ChannelOne" THEN "C1"
                        WHEN "ChannelTwo" THEN "C2"
                        WHEN "Channel2" THEN "C2"
                ELSE "Not Mapped" END AS "Channel Mapping"
FROM
ChannelFact
```

Thanks.

Comment: Works perfect!  Thanks Satishcse!

Comment: Always HTH! Although I don't know DAX :)